# How to multiply individual numbers in a list by 3 or 1 depending on the position

Tags: python-3.x

In my code, I have turned a user's input into a list and I want to multiply the user's input by 3 or 1, according to the position of the number.Example if the user enters "8748935", numbers 8,4,9 and 5 will be multiplied by 3 because their position is odd and 7,8 and 3 by 1. After multiplying all 7 numbers, I want to add them and output the result.
my current code:

```
NumGiven=''
while not NumGiven.isnumeric():
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
while len(NumGiven)<7 or len(NumGiven)>8:
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
if len(NumGiven)==8:
    list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
    total=(sum([int(i) for i in NumGiven]))
    ans = total / 10.0
    if total % 10 == 0:
        print("Your GTIN8 code is correct.")
    else:
        print("Your GTIN8 code is incorrect")
if len(NumGiven)==7:
    list=[int(x) for x in str(NumGiven)]
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: This code has nothing to do with what you want to do right?

Comment: yes it does.but what I am asking for is what I want to do.

Comment: Something along the lines of `3*sum(int(i) for i in NumGiven[::2]) + sum(int(i) for i in NumGiven[1::2])` may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the input as a list as such; [8,7,4,8,9,3,5] you could just iterate over them and apply the arithmetic as it fits

```
if len(NumGiven)==8:
  sum = 0
  list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
  for x in list:
    if list.index(x)%2 == 0:
      sum += int(x)*3 //will be applied to even indexed elements
    else: 
      sum += int(x) //will be applied to odd indexed elements
  print sum
```

Where i%2 checks if the index is even or odd (Python and I don't share your opinion of 8,4,9 and 5 being odd indexed since lists start at index 0 which makes the index of these numbers 0,2,4 and 6)

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice way to go about it(I hope)

```
mult = 3

while True:
    #Make sure input is correct
    NumGiven=input("Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number: ")
    #Uncomment if you want the length to be 7
    if NumGiven.isdigit(): #and len(NumGiven)==7:
        break

#Convert string to list of integers
NumGiven = [int(x) for x in NumGiven]

for i in range(len(NumGiven)):
    NumGiven[i]*=mult
    mult=-1*mult+4 #Some spooky business (Changes between 3 and 1, trust me)
    #Which means every first number is *=3 and the others are *=1


print(sum(NumGiven))
```

If you want the number to be of length 7, uncomment the bit I have said to and it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

My teacher helped me , :

```
if len(NumGiven)==7:
    Num0=int(NumGiven[0])*3
    Num1=int(NumGiven[1])*1
    Num2=int(NumGiven[2])*3
    Num3=int(NumGiven[3])*1
    Num4=int(NumGiven[4])*3
    Num5=int(NumGiven[5])*1
    Num6=int(NumGiven[6])*3
    print(Num0,Num1,Num2,Num3,Num4,Num5,Num6)
    total=(Num0+Num1+Num2+Num3+Num4+Num5+Num6)
    print(total)
```